# Is TfL a public body as under s17(6)(d) POA1985?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, prosecution, london

Section 17(6)(d) Prosecution of Offences Act 1985 lays out certain criteria which render an organisation subject to the prosecution rules for a public body:

> d)any other authority or body whose members are appointed by Her Majesty or by any Minister of the Crown or government department or whose revenues consist wholly or mainly of money provided by Parliament.

Does Transport for London meet these criteria?

If so, in what ways do they meet the requirement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Not under 17(6)(d) but under 17(6)(c)

[Transport for London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_for_London) is a local government body.

Section [17(6)(c)(i)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1985/23#section-17-6) allows "public authority" to be:

> (c) a local authority or other authority or body constituted for
> purposes of—
>
> (i) the public service or of local government; or